# PUG, iterar sobre una matriz de objetos nodejs

Tags: bucle-for, mongoose, crud, pug, datos

ando atorado en pug, quiero mostrar datos de mi base de datos de mongodb, mi backend funciona perfectamente, ya esta probado en Postman, el problema es; cuadno quiero mostrar los datos en pantalla solo me muestra esto:

```
recetaCTRL.listReceta = async(req, res) => {
const respuesta = await receta.find();
//console.log(respuesta)
res.render('lista', { respuesta })
    //res.json(respuesta);
```

};

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando intento mostrar solo el nombre de algún objeto tengo esto en mi pug:

```
ul li #{respuesta.name}
```

con eso me muestra un error, donde dice que "name" no esta definido, no entiendo porque espero puedan ayudarme.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que tendrías que hacer algo así:

```html
      each receta in respuesta
        ul
          li= receta.name
          li= receta.description
```

En la doc de [pug](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html) te explica.

Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono